# How to generate RSA private Key in Swift?

Tags: swift, rsa

I have encrypted a text with a public key generated using modulus and exponent, I followed that link : https://meniny.cn/posts/RSA_public_key_with_modulus_and_exponent/

I want to decrypt that text with a private key generated using another modulus and exponent.I didn't find a function in Swift or Objective-C that solve this issue.

So I use a Java code to get the private key as String and generate also a pem file.

Here is my code :

```
 let PRIVATE_KEY = "MIGxAgEAMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUABIGcMIGZAgEAAkBXIKDI5NbyZd/d5tO6djSv\rt8GDc7soyNaqSqZq/w9A/zxiZTA0uwnvYv9E+OXKS9yjPCqpu9d1ELzxQxU9KRFD\rAgEAAkAYEBbX5PvIboJpkrqfIM5kSWfUmj3ygaVn2r4jhtX7qS8+0v09fwifoeMP\r5TgmB2B8+47n8+MQ55/cKbMs2QpBAgEAAgEAAgEAAgEAAgEA\r"
    let data = PRIVATE_KEY.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    let priv =  data.base64EncodedString()
   let keyData = Data(base64Encoded: priv)!
    let dict = [
        kSecAttrKeyType: kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
        kSecAttrKeyClass: kSecAttrKeyClassPrivate,
        kSecAttrKeySizeInBits : NSNumber(value : 128),
        ] as [CFString : Any]
    let key = SecKeyCreateWithData(keyData as NSData, dict as NSDictionary, nil)
       let blockSize = SecKeyGetBlockSize(key!)
    var encrypted = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: blockSize)
    var encSize = blockSize

    let status = SecKeyDecrypt(key!,
                               SecPadding.PKCS1, x,
                               x.count, &encrypted,
                               &encSize)

   let decData = NSData(bytes: &encrypted, length: encrypted.count)
    let decString = decData.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions())
```

I always get nil for key value.

I tried to find a solution but I am unable to get the suitable private key to decrypt correctly my text.

Any help please?

Comment: I hope that private key is just test data and not an actual private key you're using.

Comment: it is not the actual private key. I put an example to show you the complete code.